# Export set of datas from django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a huge database, and I'd like to create a dump only from the latest data (let's say from the last 3 weeks, or from each table the last million lines or less).

I've collected all the models I need (with the help of `django.apps.get_app_configs()`), and all the relationships (let's say from the `User` model I need `User.objects.filter(id__gt = 1000000)`). What would be the best way to create a dump (or an export) which can be loaded easily into an empty DB.

What would be the best way? Creating a real MySQL dump, or using some `shutil`, `pickle` or `cpickle` stuff?

The best would be to have an export and an import management command for this purpose, but I'm interested at first in the techniques that can be used for this.

*The goal is to have a consistent database with minimal set of datas.*

Django: 1.7.4
DB: MySQL

Comment: That' s my problem that i' ve alltogether ~400 models and there are a lots of relationships. I tried to play with the django dumpscript and dumpdata management commands, but they' ve been designed to import whole tables, not only parts of them - as i can see.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/?

Comment: Yes, i know it, but i don' t really see how serialisation would help for me? Anyway, i tried out: serialized some data, deserialized and tried to save, but save failed on constraints.